# jQuery change all attributes within a form to something else

Tags: jquery, jquery-attributes

I have a form with form elements such as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditUserForm", @class = "form-horizontal form-bordered" }))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div><!-- form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div><!-- form-group -->

}
```

I want to use jquery to loop through all the elements within the form and to change / remove the `readonly` Attribute. When I click a button / element.

how would I go about doing this. I only know how to change the attribute of a single item which Id I know?

html is For Razor view.

Comment: It is much better to provided rendered HTML, if question is only about client side.

Comment: My code will also work for this question @zapnologica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(function () {
    $('#EditUserForm [readonly]').prop('readonly', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only input fields in your form.

Try Something like this:

```
$('input[readonly]').removeAttr('readonly');
```

OR

```
$('#EditUserForm input[readonly]').removeAttr('readonly');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eb19orp7/1/)

Comment: Yes, it looks good for me now. It's very hard to understand OP's HTML, but I think it's what is required, +1.

Comment: @Regent..yes the OP is using `Asp.Net MVC` server side technology..all..`@Html.TextBoxfor()` will generate simple textboxes...

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eb19orp7/)**

```
    $(".form-group input[type=text").each(function(){
        var attr=$(this).attr('readonly');
        if(typeof attr !==typeof undefined || attr!==false)
           $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
    });
```

Comment: `typeof attr !==typeof undefined` can be simplified into `attr !== undefined`.

Comment: No, it is just unnecessary symbols. `!==` compares looking at operands type, while `!=` looks only on values, converting them to one type.

Comment: yes , since you know this , hope you understand why this is more accurate .And you can't say this is unnecessary symbols as this will help you know the values type also .

Comment: `attr !== undefined` works as `typeof attr != typeof undefined || attr != undefined`. So, once more, as there is internal checking for type inside `!==`, there is no need to check types, just `attr !== undefined` for accurate way for checking for `undefined` value. Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stm5dc3n/) for example and a little explanation.